# Electronic controlled trash can lid eats batteries

Tags: power-supply

[image: image of power adapter used]I have installed a nine volt DC power source to take the place of the six 1 1/2 volt series-ed AA batteries, because the trash can lid circuit eats batteries. I installed the power pack after the switch which cuts out the  batteries, so in case of a PG&E power outage I can close the switch and run trash can on batteries. I want to know, if I replace the standard AA batteries with rechargeable AA batteries, can I just leave the battery switch closed with no issue of the batteries and power supply being paralleled together?

Comment: perhaps the universe is trying to tell you to stop generating so much garbage ... lol

Comment: Exactly what is this 'nine volt DC power source'?

Comment: Standard 9 VDC 3 amp power adapter plugged into 120 VAC outlet.

Comment: See image above

Comment: @jsotola or to get a trash can with a manually operated lid - foot pedal type perhaps. Saves the waste batteries as well as the electricity of the power supply 24 & 7...

Answer (score 0):

Paralleling a power supply and batteries is not recommended without some sort of circuit to make sure they don' keep being charged uncontrollably.
 First you need to tell us what type of batteries and the exact voltage on your power supply (is it regulated or unregulated). Then you can get a more accurate answer.
 However, I will try to help.
The simplest thing you can do is place a diode (Shottky preferred) going from the battery pack towards the trash can. Depending on the type of power supply, you will probably need another diode from the supply to the trash can. The first one will prevent uncontrolled charging of batteries, while the second one will prevent the slow discharge of the batteries through the power supply. Then you need a resistor across the first diode to enable a trickle charge (in case you're using NiMH cells, the trickle charge current must be 0.05C or no more than 1/20 of the capacity rating).
 The value of the resistor depends on the exact voltage of your power supply, but my rough estimate would be around 47-100 ohms.